# osgeo.gdal.Translate - How to set compression on GDAL GTiff driver

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

How do I force the use of compression on the GTiff driver when called from osgeo.gdal in Python?

Example on the workflow, which currently reads LZW tiffs and dumps them to uncompressed tiffs.

```
from osgeo import gdal,gdalconst,osr
translateoptions = gdal.TranslateOptions(rgbExpand='RGB', format='GTiff')
outFile = gdal.Translate(gdaloutput, gdalinput, options=translateoptions)
```

Would be nice to do this without the use of subprocess.

Environment:

- Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44)  [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
- gdal-2.2.2
- libgdal-2.2.2

Answer (score 12):

You have "creationOptions" for this:

```
translate_options = gdal.TranslateOptions(format = 'GTiff',
                                          creationOptions = ['TFW=YES', 'COMPRESS=LZW']
                                          )
```

Answer (score 9):

I found the answer in [this post](http://www.digital-geography.com/geotiff-compression-comparison/).

The post says

> GDAL supports three lossless compression algorithms for the GeoTiff format – Packbits, LZW and Deflate.
> You can use the compression methods with GDALs creation options.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "COMPRESS=LZW" -co "PREDICTOR=2" -co "TILED=YES" uncompressed.tiff LZW-pred2-compressed.tiff
```

In addition, adding an `options` argument using `drive.Create` may be helpful.

`driver.Create(utf8_path, xsize, ysize, bands, data_type, options=['COMPRESS=LZW'])`

Answer (score 6):

Thanks fenfen123.
I ended up using the following approach via the GDAL python api:

```py
# Write new tiffs with RGB palette
gdalinput = tile+'.tif'
gdaloutput = oFolder+'\\'+Path(tile).name+'.tif'    
translateoptions = gdal.TranslateOptions(gdal.ParseCommandLine("-of Gtiff -co COMPRESS=LZW"))
gdal.Translate(gdaloutput, gdalinput, options=translateoptions)
```

Comment: TranslateOptions (e.g. -ot -of -co) are listed on https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

Comment: Your method was helpful to me. But for anyone else looking, you can use the gdal.TranslateOptions(format="GTiff", options=['COMPRESS=LZW']) way of doing it that I think is a little cleaner. See the gdal.TranslateOptions python function for an easy way to see the full list of options.